# Quotes and Pound Sign showing as question mark

Tags: html, utf-8

I'm working on a site that takes some RSS feeds and displays them. Each feed is from a different site.

3 of the sites use UTF-8 and one iso-8859-1, however two of them don't display quotes and pound signs correctly. The iso-8859-1 site displays correctly, and one of the UTF-8 does but the other UTF-8 ones don't.

I have defined the charset to be UTF-8 in my head section.

Comment: The feed that doesn't work, does that display correctly in your browser (when you open the rss feed link in the browser)?

Comment: When I open in my browser (Safari and Chrome) I get a Can't Display RSS Feeds, Please Install Reader message. But when I check them in Google Reader they appear fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the solutions lay in the parser I was using for RSS, `MagpieRSS` which doesn't handle extra characters like '£' very well.

The solution was to switch to `SimplePie RSS`

Answer (score 2):

You can use htmlentities for display this type character like `&pound;`,

View this link http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

Comment: Indeed I can however since these are RSS feeds that would involve doing seek and replace operations on everything coming in on the feeds, so was looking for a more elegant solution that is less power intesive